# Open a project downloading from google drive failed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have a project with a few cocoapods in a folder. I run it well on my Mac. I uploaded the whole folder into google drive. Then I download it and try to open the AppName.xcworkspace.

However, there is nothing in it. It says "No files". If I open the AppName.xcodeproj, all the files are in the left side but I could not run the project.

How to open the project in this case?

Comment: Did you tried to run pod install, or pod udpate. After that maybe you can open xcworkspace file

Comment: Hi, thank you for post. I have solved it.

Comment: @GuodongRong my project is not downloadinh, how you downloaded from your drive\